# How do I calculate the flag that a coset of $SL(n) \backslash B$ stabilzes?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $SL(n)$ be the special linear group of rank $N$ and $B$ a borel subgroup. It is known that the quotient group $SL(n) \backslash B$ is a flag variety of complete flags: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144287/a-question-about-flag-variety-of-sln-mathbbc. I understand how the "standard" borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices will stabilize the "standard flag".

My question is, given a coset in $SL(n) \backslash B$, say $xB$, how do I compute the flag that it represents?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think that $xB$ stabilizes a flag? I think you are asking the wrong question. It would help if you elaborated on your problem.

Comment: Sorry, definitely typed up my question wrong. My question is accurately stated now. I just want to understand more about why the quotient group is a flag variety. In particular, given a coset, what complete flag does it correspond to?

Comment: So you want to understand how the isomorphism of $\operatorname{SL}(n)/B$ with the flag variety $\mathcal F$ is given? $\operatorname{SL}(n)$ acts on $\mathcal F$ (by acting on each subspace in a flag). Then the orbit map of the "standard flag" factors through $\operatorname{SL}(n)/B$. Explicitly, the isomorphism is given by $xB\mapsto xF$, where $F$ is the "standard flag".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative to Claudius' description in the comments. A coset $xB$ has a stabilizer $xBx^{-1}$ which is a conjugate of the Borel. Everything I'm about to say about this conjugate can be checked by checking it for the standard Borel $B$ itself.

This conjugate of the Borel fixes a unique $1$-dimensional subspace $V_1$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$; this is the first space in the flag. This induces an action on $\mathbb{C}^n/V_1$, which again fixes a unique $1$-dimensional subspace, corresponding to a $2$-dimensional subspace $V_2 \supseteq V_1$; this is the second space in the flag. Etc.